# simple method inheritance in python 3

Tags: python, inheritance

Newbie python inheritance question.. when you write the following:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("a")

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
getattr(b, "foo")
```

produces

```
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.B object at 0x000000000604CC88>>
```

It looks as if Python creates an attribute `foo` which is bound to `A.foo` and it knows that `foo` is an `A` method.

Should I think of inheritance as simply creating pointers to the base class objects (and the interpreter knows it's a base class object) as opposed to creating a copy of the attribute in the deriving class?

Seems like this is an important point but somehow wasn't clear to me initially - came to this question while playing around with `super()`.

Comment: When you do `b.foo`, Python will first look in the `__dict__` of `b` where it won’t find a `foo`. Then it will check the `mro()`, i.e. all the types in the type hierachy in order, to check where it could take a `foo` from. In your case, it would first check `B.foo` and then `A.foo`.

Comment: @poke right so i think the crux of my question was: when you do `B(A)`, `foo` isn't added to `B`'s namespace, rather `__dict__` contains all the attributes that were created specifically within `B` and not inherited from elsewhere, yeh?

Comment: The `__dict__` will only contain instance members, i.e. things where you did `self.something = value`. Methods will usually live on the class, not the instance.

Comment: @poke good to know! so then the correct way of saying it is `foo` isn't added to `B.__dict__` when you do `B(A)`, rather when you call `B.foo`, the `B.__dict__` is checked and then further up the MRO since it wasn't found?

Comment: Yup, that’s about right :)

Comment: @poke one point: when you do `b = B()` and then `b.some_method()`, is the order in which python checks things 1. instance, 2. class, 3. MRO of class? I'm just thinking of a case where you bound some method to `self`

Comment: Yes, any attribute access will work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are partially correct, let's start by what you got wrong.

> Should I think of inheritance as simply creating pointers to the base class objects

That would be incorrect. When you access an attribute, either with `getattr(obj, attr)` or by doing `obj.attr`, Python first recovers the attribute through the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). In particular this means that this *does not happen at class creation*, but at attribute lookup instead.

> It looks as if Python creates an attribute `foo` which is bound to `A.foo`

Here you are correct. Binding a class or instance method created a new object in the process.

After having recovered the attribute, Python may need to bind it. It first checks if it is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), that is an object with a `__get__` method to allow binding it to a certain instance.

Here is a Python implementation of the `getattr` to help visualize what happens when you retrieve an attribute.

First this is how Python resolves a class attribute using the *mro*.

```
def _resolve_cls_attr(cls, attr):
    if attr in cls.__dict__:
        return cls.__dict__[attr]

    elif len(cls.__mro__) > 1:
        return _resolve_cls_attr(cls.__mro__[1], attr)

    else:
        raise AttributeError('class has no attribute {}'.format(attr))
```

Then, this is how `getattr` would be implemented if it were in Python.

```
def getattr(instance, attr):
    cls = instance if isinstance(instance, type) else type(instance)

    # Recover instance attribute
    if hasattr(instance, '__dict__') and attr in instance.__dict__:
        attr_value = instance.__dict__[attr]

    # Recover the attribute from the class
    else:
        attr_value = _resolve_cls_attr(cls, attr)

    # We recovered a simple class attribute
    if not hasattr(attr_value, '__get__'):
        return attr_value

    # We recovered an instance method from a class or a staticmethod descriptor
    if instance is cls or isinstance(attr_value, staticmethod):
        return attr_value.__get__(None, cls)

    # We recovered an instance method or a custom descriptor
    return attr_value.__get__(instance, cls)
```

Keep in mind that the above omits a few steps for the sake of sticking to your question. By example, it will not rely on `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` as the builtin `getattr` would.

Comment: This is a pretty misleading and buggy way to handle descriptors. Why all the special-casing instead of just implementing the actual rule (`__get__(instance, cls)` for an instance, `__get__(None, cls)` for a class)? Also, if you're going to do descriptor handling, data descriptors are probably at least worth a mention.

Comment: @user2357112 I wrote that around 1am and could improve it a bit after a good night of sleep. Note that doc to descriptors is already linked in the answer.